# Django no encuentra mis test de manera automática, pero sí los lee cuando los pongo de manera explicita

Tags: python, django, unittest

Estoy teniendo problemas con el descubrimiento automático de tests en mi proyecto de Django. Cuando ejecuto el comando `python manage.py test` para mi aplicación completa, Django no encuentra ningún test y devuelve "Found 0 test(s)". Sin embargo, si ejecuto tests específicos o el módulo de tests, estos se ejecutan correctamente.

Esto funciona:

```bash
python manage.py test applications.inventory.tests.ItemTestCase
```

Y esto también:

```bash
python manage.py test applications.inventory.tests
```

Ambos comandos arrojan como resultado:

```
Found 1 test(s).
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.008s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Pero esto no funciona (no encuentra ningún test):

```bash
python manage.py test
```

Por otro lado, si intento ejecutar:

```bash
python manage.py test applications.inventory
```

Obtengo este error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Aquí está la estructura relevante de mi proyecto:

```
.
├── applications
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── inventory
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   └── users
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── admin.py
│       ├── apps.py
│       ├── models.py
│       ├── tests.py
│       └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── skuhub
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base.py
│   │   ├── local.py
│   │   └── prod.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── static
```

Y mi `apps.py` de **inventory** contiene:

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

class InventoryConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'applications.inventory'
```

En `settings/base.py`, INSTALLED_APPS incluye:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'applications.inventory',
    # ...
]
```

Este es el archivo `tests.py` de mi app de inventory:

```py
from django.test import TestCase

from .models import Category, Item, Product

# Create your tests here.


class ItemTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.category = Category.objects.create(name='Category test')
        self.product = Product.objects.create(name='Test product', price_real=50000)

    def test_price_fake_correction(self):
        item = Item.objects.create(product=self.product, size='M', color='Rojo', price_fake=30000, price_real=60000)

        self.assertGreaterEqual(
            item.price_fake, item.price_real, "El price_fake debería corregirse para ser igual o mayor que price_real"
        )
```

He asegurado que cada `__init__.py` esté presente y correcto, y python `manage.py` check no devuelve errores.

También mi `manage.py` hace referencia a la estructura de settings (carpeta) que tengo configurada y el servidor me corre sin problemas.

¿Qué podría estar causando este problema y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente el problema era que django no podía identificar mi módulo de aplicaciones debido a que no existia el fichero `__init__.py` dentro de la carpeta de `applications`.